# Creating a PDF for Thermal Printing using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I want to generate a PDF file which can be printed in a Thermal Label Printer (exactly it is a Zebra GK420d). I'm using the [library mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php).

The problem is the content of the file includes a table with invoice details, the library auto split the table (page break). I tried a way that is set:

1. `page-beak-inside:avoid;` in html tag of table
2. `$mpdf->use_kwt = true;` in code

But the result is unchanged.

I want to ask how can I generate a file with auto height or a certain number which is set programmatically. Please show me the way or can you suggest me another library ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific requirements do thermal printers have regarding PDF? What do you want to happen if the table does not fit in the page?

Comment: Actually I want the output would have no page cut. Which mean the paper have no break inside after printed. I'm working for a boss who is far from me and I do not have a Thermal Printer to test. Maybe we just need a normal file and the printer will do it for us ? Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, you mean a continuous feed printer!